# SQL OpenRowSet Query OLE DB not valid

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms, importerror

I have been trying to import an Excel file into my SQL Server but I seem to get this error:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"
> returned message
> "'C:\Windows\system32\Users\Desktop\Folder_name\Update_File.xlsx' is
> not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly
> and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.".
>
> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>  Cannot initialize the data
> source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked
> server "(null)".

This is the following query I used in order to import the file:

```
Select * Into EXCEL_IMPORT
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0; Database=C:Users\Desktop\Folder_name\Update_File.xlsx; HDR=YES; IMEX=1', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]');
```

I am new to SQL so I have no idea if I have everything correctly installed or if I need anything else.

Your help is much appreciated! :)

Thank you!

Comment: That surely is not a valid path.

Comment: The path in your SQL and the path in your error don't appear to match. Also does the SQL Server account have access to the `Users` directory? *Normally* it wouldn't (and shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

That path is surely not valid. Would you try (still doesn't look right to me that you have a path named liked that at all but want to believe you):

```
Select * Into EXCEL_IMPORT
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Users\Desktop\Folder_name\Update_File.xlsx; HDR=YES; IMEX=1', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]');
```